# Cannot build R file but I have NO errors in my res folder

Tags: android

I already tried: clean, restart eclipse, create and delete a dummy xml file.
if there are no errors in my res folder, what else can cause R file to not get generated.
[image]

Comment: You said you deleted xml file, are you talking about R.java and removed the android.R import?

Comment: no, someone recommended creating a dummy xml file and deleting it

Comment: Do you have an `import android.R;` in your file? If so, delete `R.java` and rebuild your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can also be issues in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Sometimes, the Eclipse Package Manager tree will not show red X marks for files that actually have errors (though it has gotten better about that). So, I'd suggest opening up `AndroidManifest.xml`, and other resources that you have recently edited, to confirm that there are no errors there.

Also, bear in mind that `R.java` is not created until you do a build. Normally, we have Build Automatically checked in Eclipse, so a build happens on each save. If you unchecked that, either re-check it or manually do a build.

You might also check the Eclipse Console tab to see if there are red error messages there.

Finally, you can try a command-line build. It used to be that I would find errors there that, for whatever reason, Eclipse was not showing me. I have not needed to do that in well over a year, but it's possible there are still some scenarios where it might be useful.

Comment: I modified the manifest fle, saved, and viola ,the errors came through.
the errors were bull s^&* errors too. it was complaining about an issue that didnt exist. All I did was delete my xml file and re create it, and paste the same code in it, and it stopped complaining.

Answer (score 0):

I often faced this issue,and what i have experienced,is that you might have named some files wrongly like (begining name with numerics characters,using some allocated words like new,integer,class...)

I hope this could help you.